# Getting error java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

From last few days I am scratching my head because of an exception mentioned below.
First of all I would request you **not to mark it as duplicate** as I already went through 
hundreds of Q & A and only in few cases answers are provided which didnt work out in my case.

Currently I an facing Protocol Violation Exception

**Stack Trace :**

> java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation at
>   oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.check_error(DBError.java:418) at
>   oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oclose.receive(Oclose.java:136) at
>   oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.closeQuery(TTC7Protocol.java:406) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.internal_close(OracleResultSet.java:145)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.next(OracleResultSet.java:81) at
>   org.apache.jsp.ditLogin_005f2_jsp._jspService(ditLogin_005f2_jsp.java:171)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

Its occurring in only one environment/server whereas in other environment/server its working fine
though both the servers are having same configuration.

**Configuration :**

**Database : Oracle 11G**

**JVM  : 64 Bit**

**Driver (OJDBC) : ojdbc6.jar**

**JDK : 1.6**

In some websites I found that password expiry date could be the reason. But in 
both the servers its null which means unlimited I guess.
So any other configuration left in which I have to look into ?
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Password expiry is null where - are you looking at the profile the user belongs to? Can you log in manually to the target DB with the credentials you're using over JDBC? I've seen this with a password expiry warning from the DB but other responses might cause it - maybe a logon trigger even. Connecting manually through another client, preferably SQL\*Plus to start with, might give you a hint.

Comment: I have checked in `dba_users` table for the user which i am using in the application. But i have not logged in manually with that user. I will check that. Thanks Alex

Answer (score 0):

The `dba_users.expiry_date` column you checked is related to the [password expire](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF54748) clause of the create/alter user commands.

The ORA-28002 error you've seen mentioned elsewhere as a possible cause of the protocol violation is related to [the user profile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF54747), specifically the [password lifetime](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF54293).

It seems the user you are connecting to in this environment has a profile which enforces password expiry through a profile, and you are currently in the grace period. You can see the assigned profile in the `dba_users.profile` column, and then see the limits in the `dba_profiles` view.

You can log in manually (which will show the warning; JDBC doesn't understand it, hence the exception you're seeing) and change it, then update your JDBC configuration to match.

Or get your DBA to change the user to a different profile, or modify the profile they are on now so it doesn't expire. You may want to do that anyway rather than changing the password at all; but it may still be quicker to change the password to resolve the immediate issue.

Comment: Its a "DEFAULT" profile and "LIMIT" column contains "UNLIMITED" in `dba_profiles` table

Comment: Hmm, OK, it was a bit of a punt. Can you edit the question to say what happened when you logged in manually through SQL\*Plus?